# Problema en la verificación de un JsonWebToken

Tags: nodejs, typescript, ionic, postman, jsonwebtoken

Estoy creando una aplicación móvil con Ionic utilizando Angular como base. Actualmente estoy trabajando en la parte del 'backend' (que no es mi fuerte) y he podido crear un usuario en una base de datos con MongoDB y loguearme exitosamente a través de Postman. El problema es que a la hora de verificar el token que estoy generando estoy recibiendo un error de 'Token inválido' que no me permite culminar ésa parte tan importante que es poder actualizar el usuario y por consiguiente continuar con mi aplicación. Dejaré el código que utilizo para la verificación de Token aquí abajo:

```
import { Response, Request ,NextFunction } from 'express';
import Token from '../classes/tokken';

export const verificaToken = (req: any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const userToken = req.get('x-token') || '';
    Token.comprobarToken( userToken )
    .then ( (decoded: any) =>{
        console.log('Decoded', decoded);
        req.user=decoded.user;
        next();
    } )
    .catch (err => {
        res.json({
            ok: false,
            mensaje: 'Tu Token está errado'
        });
    });
}
```

Aquí es en donde lo implemento:

```
userRoutes.post('/update', verificaToken, ( req: any, res: Response )=>{

    const user = {
        nombre: req.body.nombre || req.user.nombre,
        email: req.body.email || req.user.email,
        avatar: req.body.avatar || req.user.avatar
    }

    User.findByIdAndUpdate( req.user._id, user, {new: true}, (err, userDB) =>{
        if ( err ) throw err;
        if ( !userDB ) {
            return res.json({
                ok: false,
                mensaje: 'No existe un usuario con ese ID'
            });
        }
        const tokenUser = Token.getJwtToken({
            _id: userDB._id,
            nombre: userDB.nombre,
            email: userDB.email,
            avatar: userDB.avatar,
        });
        res.json({ 
            ok:true,
            token: tokenUser
        });


    } );

});

export default userRoutes;
```

He creado la función de crear usuario y la de loguearlo de manera exitosa, pero mi problema viene para actualizar los datos almacenados con el 'update'. Éste mensaje es el que me arroja en el módulo de Postman:

```
            ok: false,
            mensaje: 'Tu Token está errado'
```

Comment: Hola. Es mejor poner el código que una imagen. Tambien es necesario poner el código de `Token.comprobarToken`, al parecer el error se genera ahí. Imprime dentro del catch el error con un `console.log` de esta manera `console.log(err)` y pon la traza en la pregunta.

Comment: Lectura recomendada https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/65107

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Aquí dejo la otra parte del código:
constructor(){}
    static getJwtToken( payload: any): string{
        return jwt.sign({ 
            user: payload
        }, this.seed, {expiresIn: this.caducidad})
    }
    static comprobarToken( userToken: string ){
        return new Promise ( ( resolve, reject)=>{
            jwt.verify( userToken, (err, decoded)=> {
                if ( err ) {
                    reject();
                }else {
                   resolve( decoded );
                }  
            } )
        } );
    }
}

Comment: Hola, te sugiero leer el apartado "como preguntar?", es necesario que brindes la mayor información posible para ver lo que tienes armado y el código (no en imágenes) para poder hacer pruebas que agilizarán la solución

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código _como texto, con formato_, _en_ la pregunta. En los comentarios es ilegible.

Comment: Amigos, gracias por sus recomendaciones y disculpen mis errores de novato. Acabo de editar el post con el formato correcto y espero que ésta vez sí sea legible. Cualquier código adicional que se necesite para notar el error no duden en solicitármelo.